# Nginx server matching too many URLs

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, vhosts

I've got a domain `example.com` and an "alternative" of `some-example.com`. I'm trying to direct traffic from `some-example.com` to `example.com` using a simple server declaration in nginx as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name some-example.com;
    rewrite ^/(.*) http://example.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

I'm not 100% sure if this is the right rule, but I've got another vhost on the server, this isn't where the problem is, but it's necessary to understand the issue I'm having.

```
server {
    listen      8745;
    server_name localhost;
    <other stuff goes here>
}
```

Hitting `<my server IP>:8745` will go to that vhost, that works as intended. However I've got *another* vhost like this:

```
server {
    listen      8746;
    server_name localhost;
    <other stuff goes here>
}
```

But all of my requests to `<my server IP>:8746` hit `example.com`. I'm... baffled, I don't really grok nginx, so any help would be appreciated as to why this is happening. I mentioned that rule in the beginning because I'm thinking it has something to do with this. If additional information is needed I can supply it.

(Also, would this be better for Server Fault?)

Comment: If you remove that rewrite rule, does it solve the problem? Also, I guess you will have to provide more info (complete config file(s))

Comment: This was answered (well, I figured it out) on ServerFault. See here: http://serverfault.com/questions/113199/nginx-server-matching-too-many-urls It had to do with Wordpress bouncing URL's to my IP on port 80. I should've mentioned it ran Wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this on Server Fault also, however I found out the cause on my own. The below excerpt is pulled from [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/113199/nginx-server-matching-too-many-urls).

> It turns out this isn't an nginx
>   issue. I probably should've noted that
>   `<my server IP>:8746` runs a Wordpress
>   installation; Wordpress has an option
>   set (in the `wp_options` table, the row
>   has `option_id`  of 2 for me and
>   `option_name` of `siteurl`) to `<some
>   domain>.com`, I changed that to `<some
>   domain>.com:8746` and it worked fine.